# Formatting date() issues

Tags: php, date

I am having a problem converting a USA date to an SQL date. What could I be doing wrong?

```
$subExpiration = '09/02/2020';
$sup_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('.$subExpiration.'));
```

I also tried

```
$sup_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($subExpiration));
```

AND

```
$sup_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $subExpiration)));
```

I am just trying to convert to a formatted date of 2020-09-02 but I keep getting 1970-01-01. Seems simple. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: This is not reproducible. https://3v4l.org/lQKqE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use createFromFormat to get a date from a given format:

```
$input = '09/02/2020';
$inputformat = "m/d/Y";
$dateobj = DateTime::createFromFormat($inputformat, $input);
$yourFormat = $dateobj->format('Y-m-d');
echo $yourFormat; // 2020-09-02
```

Comment: If I use your format as written, it works. If I replace the date with a variable holding a string with the same date, it fails. Doesn't make sense.

Comment: The USA date had the time also. To just make things simpler, I just used substr() to copy only the date to the variable, and my original code worked fine. I didn't think that having a time with the date would cause a problem with converting it to Y-m-d.

Comment: Use `H:i:s` for time format like `18:30:10` (10 seconds and 30 minutes past 6PM) Where each section is: 00-23 hours, 00-59 minutes, 00-59 seconds (ie, all with leading zeroes).

Comment: So, you are saying, the code should have looked like this: date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $thedate)? substr is what I used since it was simple. I just figured if you used the format of 'Y-m-d', that it would strip out the time part, but instead, it returns a 0 for the value. Thanks.